# Lock screen has changed to an old design

Tags: screen, lightdm, lock-screen, lock

It's been two weeks since I installed Ubuntu 14.04 and today I noticed my lock screen has changed to a very old design.

[image: ugly lock screen]

I am new to Linux.

P.S. at this time light-locker is not installed in my computer. I wonder if it's necessary or not.

Comment: are you sure that its not gdm

Comment: Was your problem solved using light-locker?

Answer (score 0):

`light-locker` is necessary if you would like to have the original lock screen that Ubuntu 14.04 came with. You can install from repositories:

```
sudo apt-get install light-locker
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @Whaaaaaat I believe this is indeed an answer. Take a look at the OP's P.S.

Comment: I didn't found any official mention from ubuntu for this package and it seems that this is a third-party package

Comment: @Seth It's awfully commenty and can use an edit.

Comment: @Hamidreza No, it's in the repos. Check `apt search light-locker`.